# Animation After Background Thread Complete (iOS / Swift)

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, animation, animatewithduration

I'm looking to animate a few things when a long process (parsing) is complete. My barebones code currently looks like such:

```
func run_on_background_thread(code: () -> Void)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), code)
}

func run_on_main_thread(code: () -> Void)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), code)
}

func manage_response()
{
    run_on_background_thread
    {
        long_process()
        run_on_main_thread
        {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(animation_duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations:
                {
                    some_view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)
                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Quite obviously, the animation does not occur. The UI just updates to the final stage. What is the proper way to thread this (I know animateWithDuration() dispatch's it's own thread, but I don't know how to hold this animation until the long process is complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think U way can work. just change

```
some_view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)
```

to :

```
some_view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01)
```

change the scale value close to zero; U can see the animation occur. if scale value == 0,there is no animation occur. U can try this.

Comment: This solves the issue with scaling, but cases exist where position animations happen in one frame instead of over the passed duration.

Comment: U can and some code in  the completion and to remove the view.

Comment: Yes, I figured and implemented that. I don't think you understand the problem; the issue inconsistently (implying race condition) also exists if, inside the completion block, I for instance have:

self.some_subview.center.y += some_constant